# How to deal with a warning message about prop being mutated when testing Vue.js (^2.5.*) component

Tags: testing, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm encountering the following error message when testing a component mounted with Vue utils:

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten 
whenever the parent component re-renders. 
Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: <prop name>
```

Comment: Yes and that's absolutely fine unless the question already existed on SO, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: I've not found similar questions in relation to a component mounted in the context of a test.

Answer (score 3):

When mounting a component to be tested, to prevent the error message from being shown in the console, pass the `sync` option to false to the `mount` function. See also https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#sync